# Instrumenting memory allocations in V8 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, v8

EDIT: Seems like the new Firefox Developer Edition has the tools I need for profiling memory allocations, so I don't need the answer to this question, but I am still curious what's going on behind the scenes in Chrome though.

Why does the code below log something like

```
mdiff (10) [-91272, -824, 56, 56, 56, 528, 472, 208, 208, 208]
```

and not

```
mdiff (10) [56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 208, 208, 208, 208, 208]
```

on V8 (Chrome (or Node with adjusted script))?

I suspect that Major GC is not invoked immediately on first window.gc(). What is required to accurately measure memory allocations from JS? I don't want to invoke functions more than once because of potential side effects and for performance, since I am planning to instrument my JavaScript to have accurate memory allocation info per line of source code (actually per expression). PS: I am aware of the memory profiling tools in Chrome DevTools.

```
// noprotect

// run Chrome with --enable-precise-memory-info --js-flags="--expose-gc"
var mdiffs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var as = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function measure(i, f) {
  window.gc();
  var mem1 = window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize;
  var a = f();
  window.gc();
  var mem2 = window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize;
  var mdiff = mem2 - mem1;
  mdiffs[i] = mdiff;
  as[i] = a;
}

function falloc() {
  return {};
}

function falloc2() {
  return {0: 0};
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  measure(i, falloc);
}
for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
  measure(i, falloc2);
}

console.log("mdiff", mdiffs);
```

I started to play with V8 / Chromium source code to do what I want. First trivial patch to dump stack trace for all memory allocations that contain a function called "measure" in the call stack at https://gist.github.com/emnh/268635258f66d774d02dae64f35b46f3 .

Comment: Maybe because there is a lot of other stuff going on, that gets recycled when you call `gc` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms Maybe. So how can I prevent other stuff going on in between the calls? Perhaps it starts to work the 3rd time on because the functions get optimized and there is no time for other stuff to happen in between? I don't know.

Comment: I think your hunch is correct. Calling `window.gc` is likely not guaranteed to trigger a major GC event. I've just noticed this recently myself and literally just called `window.gc` 5 times in a row, instead. I'm seeing much more consistent garbage collection as a result of calling it multiple times.